# Is there a way to deliver a local notification instantly in Swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, notifications, ios12

I have a function and want to deliver a local notification when that function is executed. For now I've been using a Time interval notification trigger and had set the interval to 0.1s, but this doesn't feel like a proper way to deliver notification instantly because it still has a delay of 0.1s, even though it's barely noticeable.

My question is that is there a way to deliver a notification instantly, like without any delay? I've been looking for a solution to this problem but haven't found any, hope you guys could help. Thanks.

```
func didUpdateSettings() {
    //other code...
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "Notification title"
    content.subtitle = "Notification subtitle"
    content.body = "Notification body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Acording with the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-init

> trigger
>   The condition that causes the notification to be delivered. Specify nil to deliver the notification right away.

So the code would be:

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: nil)
```